# Cannot invoke 'sendData' with an argument list of type '(NSData,toPeer:NSArray,......'

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I am  new to `MultipeerConnectivity`, when I am implementing my custom `sendData` function, it shows `Cannot invoke 'sendData' with an argument list of type '(NSData,toPeer:NSArray,withMode:MCSessionSendDataMode',error:inout NSError?)`

How to fix that:

```
func sendData(dataToSend:dataSend,toPeer: MCPeerID)->Bool{
    let dataToSend = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dataToSend)
    let peerArray = NSArray(object: toPeer)
    var error:NSError?

    let arr = [MCPeerID]()
//this line shows error
    if !self.session!.sendData(dataToSend, toPeers: peerArray, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable, error: &error) {

    }
}
```

Comment: what version of Swift are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if !self.session!.sendData(dataToSend, toPeers: peerArray, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable, error: &error) {

}
```

This method doesn't return a Boolean in Swift 2.x

This is the method from the documentation from Apple

```
func sendData(_ data: NSData,
      toPeers peerIDs: [MCPeerID],
     withMode mode: MCSessionSendDataMode) throws
```

This means do you have to something like this

```
do {
    try self.session!.sendData(dataToSend, toPeers: peerArray, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable)
    print("success")
    // do something
} catch {
    print("failure")
    // do something else
}
```

Tested on Swift 2 and Xcode 7.3.1